# unexpected effects of two sections being :target at once after change of device in FF

Tags: html, css

I have developed page of simplified shape like this:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<nav></nav>

<main>
<section id ="Introduction"></section>
<section id ="aboutme"></section>

<a href="#Introduction">
  <span class="triangle__more">
      <img src="./assets/up-arrow.svg" alt="arrow up" />
  </span>
</a>

</main>

<body>
</html>
```

with css:

```
.section {
    @include clearfix();
    min-height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    display: none;
    &:target {
        display: block;
    }
```

The problem is, that if I do steps like this:

1. open the page with laptop on real laptop
2. change section to #aboutme with menu(no menu details here)
3. change device in Inspector to any of small-screen devices
4. change section to #Introduction with link in the bottom

I have both sections active(displayed) and not only #Introduction (what was my expected result).
I have also noticed that changing only screen size or orientation (and not device) does not lead to that unwelcome effect.
Could someone explain to me why it happens (is that purely FF Inspector issue)? And whether I can feel safe with that code in real life (where no-one changes device during session).

Comment: are you actually usign vanilla `CSS` or `SASS` or `LESS`? If so flag accordingly because for CSS nesting would be invalid.

Comment: Have you inspected the element that is not supposed to show, to see what rule in particular might overwrite its `display:none` from the `.section` rule ...?

Answer (score 0):

OK, finally, I think it is Firefox console bug rather. I have checked with other browser, and it is OK. Besides - when I only change the viewport wide by numbers - is OK. It really happens only when I switch device. Hopefully quite an unusual in real life.